# Making instances of forms public C#

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, function, public

I am attempting to pass information from a child form to a parent. I have been using the following code I found on a forum to help me:

**Form1.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace childform
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 tempDialog = new Form2(this);
        tempDialog.ShowDialog();
    }

    public void msgme()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Parent Function Called");
    }

}
}
```

**Form2.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace childform
{
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    private Form1 m_parent;

    public Form2(Form1 frm1)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        m_parent = frm1;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        m_parent.msgme();
    }
}
}
```

Which works and is all well and good. Trouble is, my program requires me to set variables within tempDialog, from Form 1, in methods other than button1_Click. But, these cannot find the instance of tempDialog because it is in button1_click.

Also, I cannot move it out of a method (say, into the class) because then the 'this' modifier does not reference Form1...

Any ideas how I can reference Form1 from Form2 AND vice versa? Using this code or otherwise?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by your last comment about `this`. Make a field that references `Form2` and initialize it in the constructor. Then you can reference `_form2` in other methods of `Form1`.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Form2 _form2;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _form2 = new Form2(this);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _form2.ShowDialog();
    }

}
```

This sort of thing can get difficult to follow, when complexity increases. A better way might be to make `Form1` and `Form2` have references to some common object that they can both manipulate.

Comment: Thank you, worked perfectly! I don't quite know what you mean about it getting difficult to follow, but I'm sure I'll work it out when I break something!

Answer (score 0):

You could try researching about MdiParent and Parent properties on the Form object. These allow you to get and set the parent and access their methods if required.

See [Parent property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.parent.aspx) and [MdiParent property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.mdiparent.aspx) on MSDN for further information.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your application, if you only ever have one copy of the form that you show and hide in your app, you might just be able to make a singleton static reference.  This will only work if you only instantiate the form once however and then use `show()`/`hide()` on it to make it dissappear or reappear as required.

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public static Form2 Instance;

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Instance = this;
    }
}
```

You could then access the form 2 from anywhere by using the code:

```
Form2.Instance.xxx
```